# 32 bit program won't install but dependencies are satisfied

Tags: 32-bit

Trying to install a 32 bit .deb on Kubuntu 15.10 but it says dependency problems. Despite this, all the programs listed are installed, in both 64 bit and i386. Any ideas?

```
pkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sense:i386:

sense:i386 depends on libasound2. 
sense:i386 depends on libc6. 
sense:i386 depends on libcurl3. 
sense:i386 depends on libice6. 
sense:i386 depends on libpulse0. 
sense:i386 depends on libsm6. 
sense:i386 depends on libssh-4. 
sense:i386 depends on libssl1.0.0. 
sense:i386 depends on libx11-6. 
sense:i386 depends on libxext6. 
sense:i386 depends on libxrender1. 

dpkg: error processing package sense:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

The program is Sense by the Open University, if anyone has managed to install it on Kubuntu or Debian Jessie?

Comment: How are you trying to install it exactly? It seems the package itself was built on a system prior to the introduction of Multi-Arch, so you may need to force install it (or rebuild the package if possible).

Comment: @dobey:  Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 0):

You could try force installing it.

To force install a deb package from the terminal, use one of these commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-depends package.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all package.deb
```

Sources: @dobey comment and http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/how-to-force-install-debian-packages.html

Comment: As you're a reputation 4 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!